# Deleting and Adding rows as an edit function in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

The problem is when i want to edit a song in my project which has 4 genres and let's say i want to remove 1 and save, it drops an exception. My idea was to tell the controller to remove the 4 i had on the song and add the 3 which i chose. But that would mean removing from the local database and adding the new ones, i just have no idea how to do it. Any help is appreciated. 
I made a pivot DataTable which contains song and genre ID's and which is conected to 2 other DataTables, where one has the genre types and the other song information. The listBoxFor in the view shows which genres are in the song, but when i delete one it doesn't save. I think the change needs to happen within the HttpPost of the Edit controller.
I am still new to coding and programming so I apologize if my question isn't too precise. If any more information is needed please tell me.

This is the Controller:

```
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var song = db.Songs.Find(model.SongId);
                int[] genreIds = db.SongsGenres.Where(x => x.SongId == song.Id).Select(x=> x.GenreId).ToArray();


                song.Performer = model.Performer;
                song.Title = model.Title;
                //song.Id = model.GenreIds;
                song.Year = model.Year;
                song.YoutubeLink = model.YoutubeLink;


                db.Entry(song).State = EntityState.Modified;


                foreach (var genreId in model.GenreIds)
                {

                    // tu treba ici if petlja koja izbriše stari zapis iz baze
                    // i stavi novi editirani

                    db.SongsGenres.Add(new SongsGenre
                    {
                        Song = song,
                        //SongId = song.Id,
                        GenreId = genreId
                    });
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }             

        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML(view):

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model MusicBox.Models.EditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Editiraj pjesmu</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Performer">Izvođač</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Performer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Performer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Title">Pjesma</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Year">Godina</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="YoutubeLink">Youtube link</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YoutubeLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YoutubeLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Genre">Žanr</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.GenreIds, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2", required = "required", multiple = "multiple" })
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.GenreIds, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreIds, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SongId)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Spremi" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "List")
        </div>
    </div>
}



@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".select2").select2({
            val: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GenreIds))'
        });
    </script>

}
```

EDITED.

Comment: You have posted far too much irrelevant code here - Show only that which is relevant to your issue - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example}(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "it drops an exception" What Exception is thrown? Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your code and step through it until you get to the exception. Then include the exception in your question; that will give us a good idea of what is failing.

Comment: This is the exception:

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: You need to include the error details in the question, not comments. And its telling you what to do - _See the inner exception for details) (what is the inner exception?)

Comment: I do not understand what the inner exception could be. When i click the view detail all it says is this:

{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

Comment: Possibly `db.SaveChanges();` throwing exception due to UPDATE operation (with `EntityState.Modified`) with dupe primary key being involved, or conflicted foreign key values. Provide both your model and inner exception for further details.